# Assigning specific XML Elements from string to ViewModel using AutoMapper

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-4, xpath, viewmodel, automapper

I have a database table that stores a block of XML data within a string-type field. I'd like to extract certain elements of that XML into a custom ViewModel.

In this example, the ErrorTableModel.ErrorXML holds the sample XML string. I'm attempting to get the "message" element out of that string and map it into ErrorViewModel.message.

Would this be possible to accomplish using AutoMapper?

Sample string. This data is stored in the ErrorXML property of ErrorTableModel:

```
<error
  application="TestApp"
  type="System.DivideByZeroException"
  message="Something wicked this way comes."
</error>
```

Database Model:

```
public class ErrorTableModel
{
    public int ErrorId { get; set; }
    public string ErrorXml { get; set; }
}
```

Custom ViewModel:

```
public class ErrorViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string application { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**
I've created a new helper class that is intended to assist in breaking the XML apart.

```
protected override T ResolveCore(XElement source)
{
    if (source == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(source.Value))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(source.Value, typeof(T));
}
```

I'm attempting to reference that method when I perform the mapping from the ErrorViewModel.

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<XElement, ErrorViewModel>()
        .ForMember(
            dest => dest.ErrorXml,
            options => options.ResolveUsing<XElementResolver<string>>()
                .FromMember(source => source.Element("error")
                .Descendants("message").Single()));
```

Sadly, this doesn't work... but I think I'm close.

**Update2:**

For clarification, I'd like the resulting data to look like this:

```
  ErrorViewModel.application = "TestApp"
  ErrorViewModel.type = "System.DivideByZeroException"
  ErrorViewModel.message = "Something wicked this way comes."
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: I was originally trying to break it apart using javascript, but that didn't seem like an ideal solution. I've updated my question with my latest attempt at making this work.

Comment: I will give it a try, what is the value of the ErrorXml property? Is that what you call "Sample String"? And what should the id property become?

Comment: Yes, ErrorXml contains the Sample String (I'll clarify that in the question). I'd like to break it apart using AutoMapper so that I can store the individual pieces of the XML in the ViewModel. Please check out the comments in Update2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public class ErrorConverter1 : ITypeConverter<ErrorTableModel, ErrorViewModel>
{
    public ErrorViewModel Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var dbModel = context.SourceValue as ErrorTableModel;

        if (dbModel == null) 
            return null;

        var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(dbModel.ErrorXml);

        var errorElement = xDocument.Descendants(XName.Get("error")).Single();

        return new ErrorViewModel()
        {
            id = dbModel.ErrorId,
            application = errorElement.Attribute(XName.Get("application")).Value,
            type =  errorElement.Attribute(XName.Get("type")).Value,
            message = errorElement.Attribute(XName.Get("message")).Value
        };
    }
}
```

Or through XML deserialization. For this you need to change the `ErrorViewModel` class to:

```
[XmlRoot("error")]
public class ErrorViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("application")]
    public string application { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("message")]
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorConverter2 : ITypeConverter<ErrorTableModel, ErrorViewModel>
{
    public ErrorViewModel Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var dbModel = context.SourceValue as ErrorTableModel;

        if (dbModel == null)
            return null;

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ErrorViewModel));

        var result = (ErrorViewModel) serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(dbModel.ErrorXml));

        result.id = dbModel.ErrorId;

        return result;
    }
}
```

The usage is like this:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<ErrorTableModel, ErrorViewModel>()
            .ConvertUsing<ErrorConverter1>()//or use the ErrorConverter2
            ;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());

        var dbModel = new ErrorTableModel()
        {
            ErrorId = 1,
            ErrorXml =
                "<error application=\"TestApp\" type=\"System.DivideByZeroException\" message=\"Something wicked this way comes.\"></error>"
        };

        var viewModel = Mapper.Map<ErrorTableModel, ErrorViewModel>(dbModel);

        Console.WriteLine(viewModel.id);
        Console.WriteLine(viewModel.application);            
        Console.WriteLine(viewModel.type);
        Console.WriteLine(viewModel.message);

    }
}
```

Add guard clauses to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for spending some time to work this out. I did change the "ConvertUsing" to "ConstructUsing" in order to maintain the ID. Other than that, its working perfectly for me!